# How do you change the default cursor set for a webpage?

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

I am trying to replace all of the cursors on my webpage with custom .curs. I know about using

```
cursor: url(uri);
```

but what I really want to do is replace the default pointer, text, default, etc. with my own. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do that by setting the cursor property to different values for different elements, imitating the way browsers use different cursors. For example,

input[type=text] { cursor: url(text.cur), text; }

Browsers don’t all behave the same way, and the [description of rendering in the HTML5 draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html) does not describe browser behavior in much detail in this area. It contains just notes and special settings:

```
a:link[rel~=help], a:visited[rel~=help],
area:link[rel~=help], area:visited[rel~=help] { cursor: help; }
```

This could be one of the rules you could imitate. But most of the rules you would need to find out yourself, I’m afraid. Strangely, even the “Default style sheet for HTML 4” in the CSS 2.1 spec does not set the cursor property at all.

If I wanted to do such things I would probably take a list of HTML elements (either some extensive list or a list of elements that I actually use) and think about the cursor shape for each of them, doing some testing in browsers as needed.

But for usability reasons, I would hesitate to customize cursor shapes, except perhaps in specialized applications.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't do it. I, as a user, don't like when web pages fiddle with my custom settings.

Comment: Well, I see what you are saying, but I am trying to give it a fun and  less professional look, so I wanted more humorous cursors